# Is there a Twilio Bulk SMS Api other than Notify?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a system that needs to send > 50k SMS customized SMS messages.  I would like to do this with the fewest API calls possible due to some other constraints.

Most of the answers here will point me to **Twilio Notify**, which has reached the end of its life this year.

I looked into the **Messaging Service**, but the API for that still takes one message per API call. Before I build my own solution,

I want to confirm that Twilio does not provide this any longer, correct?

It looks like some people suggest **firebase** through a firestore integration, anything else like that out there?

Answer (score 1):

***Update Jan 2024***

You're right, Twilio Notify was the go-to product for new customers that have this use-case. Please note that existing customers can still use Notify until its planned [EOL date, which is currently December  2025](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/notify-api-end-of-life-further-extension-notice).

The good news is that we're planning to release a messaging feature that can also be used to send bulk messages with a single API call by then. I'm afraid this is all I can share for now, but please don't hesitate to reach out to support or your sales contact if you'd like to learn more.